# Path issue for scripts/css loading in Angular2 quickstart app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm following the "Setup" tutorial on the Angular website (https://angular.io/guide/setup).

When using `npm start`, the page is correctly served and displayed as expected. However, my end goal is to serve the page with a mongoose server, and I'm not succeeding.

---

Actually, what I'd need to understand is the following.

Here is the directory/files tree of the project:

```
myapp
|--src
|  |-- index.html
|  |-- styles.css
|  |-- ...
|--node_modules
|  |-- ...
```

Here is an extract of `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    ...
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  </head>
...
</html>
```

The stylesheet path and the JS script path are not *valid from the same location*.

**Then, how is a server supposed to know that:**

- `styles.css` should be loaded from `myapp/src/`

(`myapp/src/styles.css`)

- `node_modules/.../zone.js` should be loaded *directly from* `myapp`

(`myapp/node_modules/.../zone.js`)

Comment: You'd better use angular-cli, as explained here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Well, using angular-cli, there is even more questionning: the basic `index.html` file references no script or stylesheet, yet when served via `ǹg serve -o` some `<script>` tags appear.

Comment: So... what is your question about that?

Comment: Well the question remains the same somehow: how is it possible to do that (either serving resources from two different locations (as mentionned in my original question) or having the server add a `<script>` tag on the fly (as mentionned in my comment)) with a standard basic http server? It seems impossible to directly use the QuickStart/Angular-cli-generated app folder as-is with a classic http server. The `ng serve`/`ng start` command seems to do more than just serving a page.

Comment: You use ng build [--prod], and you serve the content of the generated dist directory with your web server. Read https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories for a whole lot of information about the CLI.

Comment: Ok, the `ng build` step was for me the missing piece!